# Why does my supposedly scrolling canvas not scroll, or extend the height of the containing frame?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, scrollbar

**Update:** I added more of the relevant code. Sorry for the omission.

Here's what I'd like to do: I'd like for my program's interface to include a scrolling bit of canvas in the right hand side of the main window. Ultimately, this canvas should scroll independently and I should be able to stick widgets on it.

What I have now is a good start, but, for some reason the canvas neither scrolls, nor extends the height of the window.

I'm new here, so I'd like to ask for your patience with my ignorance. I've shortened the code considerably and, if there's something I need to add, please tell me.

```
class MainApplication(Frame):
def __init__(self, master = None):
    '''We all know what this is.'''
    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    mixer.init()
    self.grid()
    self.master = master
    # Fullscreenness: from effbot.org
    w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
    root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))
    root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 3)
    self.window = Frame(self, relief = SUNKEN)
    self.window.grid(sticky = 'nsew')
    self._menuSetup()    # Generates the menubar
    self._windowSetup()  # Here is where the window is supposed to be

# There are a bunch of other methods skipped here

def _windowSetup(self):
    '''Sets the window up'''
    def onTickerConfigure(event):
        self.tickerCanvas.configure(scrollregion = self.tickerCanvas.bbox('all'))
    def setupRightTicker():
        '''Eventually, this will be a lot more complicated, but for now it just puts some stuff into the
        ticker.'''
        textOne = TickerEntry('Welcome to the Brew Manager!', self)
        textOne.grid(sticky = 'we')
        textTwo = TickerEntry('Your Brewery Needs to be Set Up', self, self.brewerySetup)
        textTwo.grid(sticky = 'we')
        for test in range(20):
            text = TickerEntry('This is a test entry '+str(test), self)
            text.grid(sticky = 'we')
        self.window.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 3)
    self.window.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight = 1, minsize = 100)
    self.rightTickerFrame = Frame(self.window, width = 100, relief = FLAT)
    self.noteFrame = Frame(self.window, width = 600, relief = FLAT)
    self.noteFrame.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    self.rightTickerFrame.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = 'nse', ipadx = 5, ipady = 5)
    self.rightTickerPad = Frame(self.rightTickerFrame, border = 0, height = 15, relief = FLAT)
    self.rightTickerPad.grid()        
    self.tickerBox = Frame(self.rightTickerFrame, border = 1, relief = FLAT, pad = 3)
    self.tickerBox.grid(sticky = 'nswe')
    self.tickerCanvas = Canvas(self.tickerBox, borderwidth = 0)
    self.ticker = Frame(self.tickerCanvas, borderwidth = 0)
    self.tickerScroll = Scrollbar(self.tickerBox, orient = 'vertical', command = self.tickerCanvas.yview())
    self.tickerCanvas.configure(yscrollcommand = self.tickerScroll.set)
    self.tickerScroll.pack(side = 'right', fill = 'y')
    self.tickerCanvas.pack(side = 'left', fill = 'both', expand = True)
    self.tickerCanvas.create_window((4,4), window = self.ticker, anchor = 'nw', tags = self.ticker)
    self.ticker.bind('<Configure>', onTickerConfigure)
    # Setup the Righthand Ticker
    setupRightTicker()
    # Setup the notebook
    noteWidth = root.winfo_screenwidth() - 300
    noteHeight = root.winfo_screenheight() - 110
    self.note = Notebook(self.noteFrame, width = noteWidth, height = noteHeight)
    self.note.grid(sticky = 'nsw')
```

Here's what my code is currently generating:
[image: Image of my Tkinter interface]

Most of my code is based on stuff I've found here (stackoverflow) on other questions on how to make a scrolling frame in Tkinter. I'm sure that I'm just doing something stupid, but for the life of me, I can't find it.

Can someone else?

Comment: You didn't show us the code that creates any canvas widgets or where you add anything to a canvas, and your code has indebtation errors.

Comment: @BryanOakley: Sorry for the omission. I've included the relevant code.

Comment: You still have indentation errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you pack/place/grid widgets in a canvas they won't scroll. You need to use the `create_window` method. If you add widgets with `create_window`, it won't affect the size of the canvas. You can't get both behaviors at the same time because they are contradictory.

My suggestion is to start from scratch. Start with the smallest amount of code possible to build your main window layout. Add the canvas and whatever other high level frames you have. Give them all distinct colors so you can visualize where one widget ends and the next begins. You might need to give the frames an artificial size to start with. Do this, and get the main areas of your app to appear and behave the way you expect. Make sure everything resizes properly when you resize the window.

Then, and only then, start adding the interior widgets. Doing it this way means you aren't trying to solve multiple layout problems at once. As it stands, your problems could be in how you are managing the interior widgets, or the high level frames, or both.

Comment: But I should be able to assign dimensions, shouldn't I? Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: Yes, you can assign dimensions. As written in the example, your canvas has a requested width of 1 (one) and a height of 1 since you don't give it an explicit size. It's eventual size depends on the other widgets in your application.